# WebStorm stopping at breakpoints even after I have removed (or disabled) them -- React application

Tags: reactjs, debugging, webstorm

I'm very new to using WebStorm's debugger but it seems simple enough. Set up the configuration (in this case JavaScript for React), then start the React app using terminal, then hit debug. Then set breakpoints.

It seems to work fine except it's stopping at lines of code where there are no breakpoints (i.e., no red circle to the left of the code line), over and over again -- and also, when I have a breakpoint set, for example in Render in the JSX code, and I either disable it (using the menu, which seems to leave an empty green circle), or click to remove it entirely (no red or green circle), the debugger *keeps* stopping at that line.

What am I doing wrong?

As an additional, optional question, what's your experience when using the WS debugger with React apps?  I'm used to WS, so thought to explore the WS debugger, which seems extremely powerful, but others use the VSC/Chrome route...

WebStorm 2018.2.3, MacOS 10.13.5, React ^16.5.2

Comment: stopping at wrong lines likely indicates source maps issues; sample project + steps to repeat would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I was clicking on 'run to cursor' instead of 'run' in the debugger panel.  Doh!